# How to achieve an "overflowing" riplle-effect in android

Tags: java, android, ripple, rippledrawable

I saw this kind of riplle effect in YouTube's android app. I want to get the same effect working in my app. Should I create an own Ripple-Drawable or is there a different approach?
Actually I already tried "?attr/selectableItemBackground" but the effect is much different.
[image: The ripple effect I want to achieve]

This is how my ripple effect looks:
[image]

Comment: This is handled by Material Design through AppCompat themes. Learn about those here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: @shkschneider Thanks. I guess i already figured out my problem.

Comment: If so, please don't hesite to answer your own question and validate it ;)

Comment: Try to use `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Comment: @shkschneider My answer will be online soon I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the value `?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` to  `android:foreground` or `android:background`

Be sure to use the android namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can create ripple from selector .See below example .

1.This is for API 21 and above, Create this in drawable

**custom_ripple.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/line" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

2.Add same name file in drawable-v21 for below 21 API.

**v1/custom_ripple.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/line">

<item
    android:id="@android:id/mask"
    android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</ripple>
```

and finally set android:background="@drawable/custom_ripple" , where you want ripple.